# It didn't wok for key Ctrl+B+D, when I using tmux on mac

Tags: tmux

I am trying to use tmux but all keys didn't work on my mac.

I am using zsh. and I didn't find out ~/.tmux.cnf

Comment: Did you release the control key before pressing D?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't
For example when you want to press:

```
prefix + d
```

It means `prefix` **then** `d`. You do:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (default prefix)
- release those keys
- press <kbd>d</kbd>

The default config file for tmux is `~/.tmux.conf` not `cnf`